# code optimization for multiple array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array

```
[{ Name: 'CVS 7201 Us Highway 64',Address: '7201 Us Highway 64',CustomerID: 'FB7BCE3B-E06E-420A-A342-08CF20054F78'},
{ Name: 'CVS 9931 Gilead Road', Address: '9931 Gilead Road',CustomerID: '920FAEF9-826B-4DE6-98F7-07E2201D5020'},
{ Name: 'Walgreens',Address: '2805 N Roosevelt Blvd',CustomerID: 'FB7BCE3B-E06E-420A-A342-08CF20054F78'}]

[{TenantID:1,External_ID:'920FAEF9-826B-4DE6-98F7-07E2201D5020'},
{TenantID:2,External_ID:'FB7BCE3B-E06E-420A-A342-08CF20054F78'}]
```

Filtered Data

```
[{ Name: 'CVS 7201 Us Highway 64',Address: '7201 Us Highway 64',TenantID:2},
{ Name: 'CVS 9931 Gilead Road', Address: '9931 Gilead Road',TenantID:1},
{ Name: 'Walgreens',Address: '2805 N Roosevelt Blvd',TenantID: 2}]
```

In my first array there are  more then 5K record and in second array it's around 100+
I write some code but i am not happy with the way.

```
for (const data of recordset.recordset) {//5000
    for(var i in lstAllTenant){//120
        if(lstAllTenant[i].External_ID == data.CustomerID)
        {
            var pickupLocations = {
                TenantID: lstAllTenant[i].TenantID,
                Name: data.Name,
                Address: data.Address,
            }
            lstPickupLocations.push(pickupLocations);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i optimize this thing?

Comment: Nothing [here](https://www.google.nl/search?q=javascript+update+object+array+with+data+from+other+object+array+site:stackoverflow.com) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way:

```js
const array1 = [{ Name: 'CVS 7201 Us Highway 64',Address: '7201 Us Highway 64',CustomerID: 'FB7BCE3B-E06E-420A-A342-08CF20054F78'},
{ Name: 'CVS 9931 Gilead Road', Address: '9931 Gilead Road',CustomerID: '920FAEF9-826B-4DE6-98F7-07E2201D5020'},
{ Name: 'Walgreens',Address: '2805 N Roosevelt Blvd',CustomerID: 'FB7BCE3B-E06E-420A-A342-08CF20054F78'}];

const array2 = [{TenantID:1,External_ID:'920FAEF9-826B-4DE6-98F7-07E2201D5020'},
{TenantID:2,External_ID:'FB7BCE3B-E06E-420A-A342-08CF20054F78'}];

const filteredArray = array1.map(({ Name, Address, CustomerID}) => ({
      Name,
      Address,
      TenantID: array2.reduce((acum, { TenantID, External_ID }) => (External_ID === CustomerID ? TenantID : acum), null)
  }));

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: thanks, as per my requirement your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

How about this

```js
const source = [{ Name: 'CVS 7201 Us Highway 64',Address: '7201 Us Highway 64',CustomerID: 'FB7BCE3B-E06E-420A-A342-08CF20054F78'},
{ Name: 'CVS 9931 Gilead Road', Address: '9931 Gilead Road',CustomerID: '920FAEF9-826B-4DE6-98F7-07E2201D5020'},
{ Name: 'Walgreens',Address: '2805 N Roosevelt Blvd',CustomerID: 'FB7BCE3B-E06E-420A-A342-08CF20054F78'}]

const ids = [{TenantID:1,External_ID:'920FAEF9-826B-4DE6-98F7-07E2201D5020'},
{TenantID:2,External_ID:'FB7BCE3B-E06E-420A-A342-08CF20054F78'}]

const result = source.map(i => {
i.TenantID = ids.find(id => id.External_ID === i.CustomerID).TenantID;
delete i.CustomerID;
return i
}) 

console.log(result)
```

Keep in mind that while this is probably simple solution, it does mutates your `source` (deletes CustomerID). Non-mutating version is a bit longer and is not difficult, you can achieve it on your own, if you want.

Comment: Array.prototype.map() is indeed the best function! (you where quicker!)

Comment: @PeterBode Yeah, I have the fastest hand in the West)

Answer (score 1):

What you could also do since you have a large number of items is to utilize [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for a concise and performant solution:

```js
const data = [{ Name: 'CVS 7201 Us Highway 64', Address: '7201 Us Highway 64', CustomerID: 'FB7BCE3B-E06E-420A-A342-08CF20054F78' }, { Name: 'CVS 9931 Gilead Road', Address: '9931 Gilead Road', CustomerID: '920FAEF9-826B-4DE6-98F7-07E2201D5020' }, { Name: 'Walgreens', Address: '2805 N Roosevelt Blvd', CustomerID: 'FB7BCE3B-E06E-420A-A342-08CF20054F78' } ]
const arr = [{ TenantID: 1, External_ID: '920FAEF9-826B-4DE6-98F7-07E2201D5020' }, { TenantID: 2, External_ID: 'FB7BCE3B-E06E-420A-A342-08CF20054F78' } ]

const map = arr.reduce((r,c) => (r.set(c.External_ID, c.TenantID), r), new Map())

const result = data.map(({Name, Address, CustomerID}) => 
   ({TenantID: map.get(CustomerID), Name, Address}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a test of this - it is non destructive

```js
const arr1 = [{ Name: 'CVS 7201 Us Highway 64',Address: '7201 Us Highway 64',CustomerID: 'FB7BCE3B-E06E-420A-A342-08CF20054F78'},
{ Name: 'CVS 9931 Gilead Road', Address: '9931 Gilead Road',CustomerID: '920FAEF9-826B-4DE6-98F7-07E2201D5020'},
{ Name: 'Walgreens',Address: '2805 N Roosevelt Blvd',CustomerID: 'FB7BCE3B-E06E-420A-A342-08CF20054F78'}]

const arr2 = [{TenantID:1,External_ID:'920FAEF9-826B-4DE6-98F7-07E2201D5020'},
{TenantID:2,External_ID:'FB7BCE3B-E06E-420A-A342-08CF20054F78'}]

let merged = arr1.map(item => {
  let item2 = arr2.find(itm2 => itm2.External_ID === item.CustomerID);
  if (item2) {
    let newItem = Object.assign({ }, item); 
    newItem.TenantID=item2.TenantID;
    delete newItem.CustomerID; // I am sure there is a way to copy only name and address using { Name, Address } = item
    return newItem;
  }  
});
console.log(merged)
console.log(arr1)
```